# Async methods cannot have ref or out parameters

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I want to call email notification using **asynchronously**

```
   public void UpdatePassDetailsForLostCase(LostPassRequest objLostPassRequest, out TransactionalInformation transaction)
    {
        transaction = new TransactionalInformation();

        try
        {
            _passDataService.UpdatePassDetailsForLostCase(objLostPassRequest);

            transaction.ReturnStatus = true;
            transaction.ReturnMessage.Add("Pass details updated successfully.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.ReturnMessage.Add(ex.Message);
            transaction.ReturnStatus = false;
        }
    }
```

This is what I have tried but it is giving me an error

> "Async methods cannot have ref or out parameters".

```
    public async void UpdatePassDetailsForLostCase(LostPassRequest objLostPassRequest, out TransactionalInformation transaction)
    {
        transaction = new TransactionalInformation();

        try
        {
            _passDataService.UpdatePassDetailsForLostCase(objLostPassRequest);

            await EmailNotificationAsync(1, "LostPass", "LostPass");

            transaction.ReturnStatus = true;
            transaction.ReturnMessage.Add("Pass details updated successfully.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.ReturnMessage.Add(ex.Message);
            transaction.ReturnStatus = false;
        }
    }

Task<int> EmailNotificationAsync(string passId, string actionName, string moduleName)
    {
        return Task.Run<int>(() =>
        {
            return EmailNotification(passId, actionName, moduleName);
        });
    }

 private int EmailNotification(string passId, string actionName, string moduleName)
    {
        try
        {
            //Email Send Code
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            InsertErrorLog(moduleName, "EmailNotification", ex.Message); // Add error in database.
        }
        return 1;
    }
```

> Give the error:
>
> Error CS1988 Async methods cannot have ref or out parameters

How can I workaround this?

Comment: @GaneshManickam Consider helping him first rather than kicking him out from the community.

Comment: I think this question is perfectly fine and I'm frankly trying to figure this out myself.